# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, table-alias

```
select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      rating, 
      avg(age) as avgage 
    from 
      sailors 
    group by 
      rating
  ) as temp 
where 
  temp.avgage = (
    select 
      min(temp.avgage) 
    from 
      temp
  );
```

When i am trying to run the above command i am getting the following error

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

The Sailors table looks like this
[Sailors Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lGwM.png)

Could you tell why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table aliases in Oracle don't have `AS` (columns can, but don't have to).

Therefore:

```
No :   ) as temp 
Yes:   ) temp
```

---

As of ORA-00942: `temp` isn't *accessible* in a subquery. But, if you use it (the `temp`) as a CTE or an inline view (so that it is a *source* readable by the whole query), then it should be OK. Something like this:

```
with temp as
  (select rating, avg(age) as avgage
   from sailors
   group by rating
  )
select *
from temp a
where a.avgage = (select min(b.avgage)
                  from temp b
                 );
```

Comment: If i removed the aliases i am getting the ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error

Comment: I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: Hey! Could tell me where can i learn oracle sql including the pl/sql part.

Comment: I used documentation. You didn't specify database version you use (and I doubt it is an old 10g), but - this page: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/index.htm contains books placed into useful sections. I'd suggest 3 books: SQL Reference, PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference and Application Developer's Guide - Fundamentals. Find the ones appropriate to your database version (or start with what I suggested, then learn the differences (new functions etc.)).

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the version, I want to learn Oracle 11g version. Thanks for the suggestions.